# Compile Error Extra ')' - System Debug

Tags: apex, debugging

My code:

```
public class createController {
     system.debug('hello');
}
```

My Error:

> createController Compile Error: Extra ')', at 'hello'. at line 2
>   column 14

The debug returns when I use the Execute Anonymous Window through Developer Console.

Comment: This is invalid class. Class can not contain code block "as is" in apex, but can have methods with code block, which can have multiple code blocks with code statements. https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3214/class-java  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/quickstart-apex/steps/quickstart-apex-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class can hold things like methods and variables. If you rewrote your code as:

```
public class createController {
    public void sayHello() {
        System.debug('Hello');
    }
}

createController test = new createController();
test.sayHello();
```

Then your debug log will show 'Hello'

Comment: Those last two lines can't be part of the class either.

Comment: Yep, they're outside the class. I was giving an example that gives a result in the 'Execute Anonymous' window

Comment: Ah okay might want to tweak the phrasing to indicate as much.